# What's about Nasa agreement for waking up ICE/ISEE-3?

Tags: nasa, probe

The ICE/ISEE-3 spacecraft is in space since 1978. It'll return near the Earth in august 2014. can we contact it to put it in L1 Lagrange point ? Is it too old ? The decision is in the hands of Nasa.

Comment: [This page](http://science.slashdot.org/story/14/03/04/024207/nasa-forgets-how-to-talk-to-iceisee-3-spacecraft) suggests, no.  Or at least, the tech. to communicate it has been removed, and no-one is willing to pay the cost of making it again.

Comment: [Obligatory XKCD](https://xkcd.com/1337/). Coincidentally, it's the comic no. 1337, which is kinda leet :=) Explanation for the comic is [here](http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php?title=1337)